# SonarQube for python is ignoring __init__.py files

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Running SonarQube in my CI pipeline is excluding all `__init__.py` files in the source directory.

```
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   **/__init__.py
```

Is there a way to configure this in the `sonar-project.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sonar.exclusions`

```
sonar.exclusions = **/__init__.py
```